# TikZ - Two Colored Circle Split

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I need to draw a two-colored `circle split`, exactly as is specified in the section 39.6 of the manual for `rectangle splits`, meaning that one half of the `circle split` has one fill color and the other half a different fill color. I have to rotate it afterwards, but that is not a problem.

For rectangle splits is seems to be as easy as adding the option `rectangle split part fill={red, blue}` in the definition. Is there a similar way to multiple-color circle splits?

Greetings from Chile,
Marcelo.

Comment: no the option `circle split part fill` does not exist.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Final code**

**Correction of bugs**

1) `\begin{scope}[on background layer]` is not useful.

2)  Instead of `\insiderad-0.5\pgflinewidth`, the correct code is `\insiderad-\pgflinewidth`

The style `circle split part fill` needs two colors like in  `circle split part fill={blue!50,red!50}`

Here a complete example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,calc}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{circle split part fill/.style  args={#1,#2}{%
 alias=tmp@name, % Jake's idea !!
  postaction={%
    insert path={
     \pgfextra{% 
     \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\pgf@node@name}{center}}%
                  {\pgfpointanchor{\pgf@node@name}{east}}%            
     \pgfmathsetmacro\insiderad{\pgf@x}
      %\begin{scope}[on background layer]
      %\fill[#1] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.east) arc
      %                    (0:180:\insiderad-0.5\pgflinewidth)--cycle;
      %\fill[#2] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.west)  arc
      %                     (180:360:\insiderad-0.5\pgflinewidth)--cycle;  
      \fill[#1] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.east) arc
                          (0:180:\insiderad-\pgflinewidth)--cycle;
      \fill[#2] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.west)  arc
                           (180:360:\insiderad-\pgflinewidth)--cycle;            %  \end{scope}   
         }}}}}  
 \makeatother  

\begin{document}

\Huge  

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[shape=circle split,
    draw=gray!40,
    line width=1mm,text=white,font=\bfseries,
    circle split part fill={blue!50,red!50}
    ] at (5,5) {text\nodepart{lower}lower};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[name=s,
    shape=circle split,
    draw=gray!40,
    line width=10mm, minimum width =5cm,
    circle split part fill={blue!50,red!50}
    ] at (5,5) {text\nodepart{lower}lower};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=s,
    shape=circle split,
    draw=gray!40,line width=2mm,
    circle split part fill={blue!50,red!50}
    ] at (5,5) {Big text\nodepart{lower} very big lower};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**A workaround (the first idea):**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}

\Huge
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name=s,shape=circle split,draw=gray!40,line width=4mm,minimum size=8cm] {text\nodepart{lower}lower};
  \foreach \anchor/\placement in
    {north west/above left, north/above, north east/above right,
     west/left, center/below, east/right,
     mid west/right, mid/above, mid east/left,
     base west/left, base/below, base east/right,
     south west/below left, south/below, south east/below right,
     text/left, lower/left, 130/above}
     \draw[shift=(s.\anchor)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)}
       node[\placement] {\scriptsize\texttt{(s.\anchor)}}; 

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[blue!50] (s.base) ([xshift=-4mm]s.east) arc (0:180:4cm-2mm)--cycle;
    \fill[red!50] (s.base) ([xshift=4mm]s.west) arc (180:360:4cm-2mm)--cycle;  
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's not easy to make a style from this code. Finally it was possible !

Comment: You are right. I tried it but I got an error perhaps with a problem of syntax. Thanks !

Comment: Wow, this is just awesome. It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot @Altermundus!

Comment: Thanks, but I corrected several bugs and modified the code several times, perhaps small bugs also may still exist.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: this is quite handy, however it does not accept `none` as a fill, could you point me to a solution for that? ANy chance this makes it into TikZ?

Comment: Is there any reason why using `\nodepart[fill=black!20]{upper}` and `\nodepart[fill=red!20]{lower}` does not work? (hope I got the syntax correct) ; the pgf manual suggests it should be doable using `\nodepart[⟨options⟩]{⟨part name⟩}` on page 232.