# "append after command" in a tree (child path operation)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees

*Related: [Problem with "append after command" and "insert path"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55722/5699), but I did not understand how to apply the solutions there in my case.*

I'm defining a simple tikz style which uses `append after command`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  fit after/.style={
    append after command={%
      node[draw, inner sep=0pt, fit=(\tikzlastnode)] {}
    }
  }
  ]
  \node[fit after] {A};%%%% WORKS
  \node {B} child { node[fit after] {C} }; %%%% FAILS
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On the first node (`A`), it works fine and draws a rectangle around it.

On the `C` node, however, I get the following error message:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named  is known.
```

The `\tikzlastnode` isn't at fault, as even hardcoding the name of the node still fails in the `child` case.

Is the `child` path operation messing with `append after command`? Is there a workaround?

*Context: I am trying to make a `triangle fit whole subtree` command, which draws a triangle that fits around all the nodes in the subtree.*

Comment: I would definitely use Forest for this.

Comment: @cfr: Could you expand on what features of the `forest` package you would use in this case? Do you mean that `append after command` would work better with `forest`? I skimmed over the documentation, but nothing stroke me. Thanks!

Comment: See below for an example. Forest parses the tree in cycles. This means that you can collect up the list of nodes in the subtree after the entire tree is specified and then use that list as the argument for `fit`. I doubt `append after command` would work straightforwardly because it would probably conflict with Forest's own functions. But the point is that you don't really need it with Forest. (I'm not entirely sure how it would work in your example either, but I accept that you had something in mind. :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `forest` is an option, it is reasonably straightforward to define a `fit whole subtree` style. I don't recommend a triangular shape. Although I experimented a bit, this inevitably looked very ugly. However, `fit whole subtree` can be passed whatever options you wish to style the node. By default, it draws a rectangle in red.

Note that multiple uses of `fit whole subtree`, including nested uses, work fine.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\makenodename[1]{(#1)}
\forestset{
  declare toks={fit these}{},
  fit whole subtree/.style={
    delay={
      temptoksa=,
      for tree={%
        temptoksa+/.wrap pgfmath arg={ (##1)}{name()},
      },
      fit these/.register=temptoksa,
      delay={
        tikz+={
          \node [draw=red, fit=\foresteoption{fit these}, inner sep=0pt, #1] {};
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    fit=band,
    child anchor=parent,
    parent anchor=children,
  }
  [A
    [B
      [C, fit whole subtree
        [D]
        [E
          [X]
          [Y
            [Z]
          ]
        ]
        [F]
        [G]
      ]
      [H
        [I
          [J]
          [K]
          [L]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [M, fit whole subtree={thick, draw=blue, rounded corners}
      [N
        [O
          [R]
        ]
        [P]
        [Q]
      ]
      [S, fit whole subtree={green, densely dashed, rounded corners}
        [T]
        [U]
        [V]
        [W]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: nested fitted subtrees]

Comment: I had to upgrade to the latest version of Forest (`/.register` was introduced in v2.0) and install `elocalloc` from CTAN. Works great after that!

Comment: Yes, it does need version 2. You could do this with the earlier version but you'd probably need to use `TeX` and fiddle with adding the nodes to a macro. Upgrading is definitely the way to go!