# Wrap text around wide figure in two column

Tags: two-column, wrapfigure

[image]I need to insert a figure into a two column document such that the figure partially spans both columns, and the text wraps around it.  It seems `wrapfig` does not work for this in two column, `pullquote` does not seem to either be exactly what I need.  I've tried using `minipage` with no luck. I tried to post an example of what I need to accomplish but since I am new this forum I cannot.  I'd be happy to send an image if this helps.

Any suggestions would be fantastically helpful!

Comment: welcome to tex.sx. we can probably guess from the description but you can upload a picture: use the image upload button but remove the `!` from the generated markup. This uploads the image, someone with edit rights will put the `!` back.

Comment: Yes, `wrapfig` can be used here. The document [multiple-span.txt](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/multiple-span.txt) explains how to use `wrapfig` with two-column cutouts.

Comment: The first answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert) seems to cover many possibilities.  In what way does `pullquote` fail?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45958/implementing-a-pullquotes-algorithm-in-latex

Answer (score 18):

The document [multiple-span.txt](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/multiple-span.txt) explains how to use `wrapfig` with two-column cutouts. Three little examples showing the layout od the image in the question and two other possible configurations:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{18\baselineskip}Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci \begin{wrapfigure}[19]{l}[\dimexpr\columnwidth+\columnsep\relax]{12cm}
\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=16\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a wrapfigurein a two-column cutout}
\end{wrapfigure}et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]\begin{wrapfigure}[18]{r}[\dimexpr\columnwidth+\columnsep\relax]{12cm}
\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=16\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla.\vspace{18\baselineskip} Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]\begin{wrapfigure}[18]{r}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{8cm}
\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=16\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et\begin{wrapfigure}[18]{l}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{8cm}
\vfill
\end{wrapfigure} magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The document contains detailed instructions for the procedure. This approach requires manual intervention, so this should be done once the document is close to its final version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!  I was able to update the post by adding a figure for what I'm trying to do.  Rather than locating the figure relative to the text "by hand" using wrap fig., is it possible to locate and/or float specifically to the top left corner of the page?

Comment: @user33755 No; at least not with this approach. Using `wrapfig` for two-column cutouts requires manual intervention.

Comment: @user33755 I updated my answer with the settings required to produce a layout similar to the one in your image. Manual intervention is needed, though, as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: thanks again for your help. Indeed this provides the desired result, however, the need to manually place the figure is fairly restrictive and seems counter to the latex philosophy.  I have been looking around all day for a more robust approach to this and am surprised there isn't a solution that more readily accommodates this fairly typical magazine style layout.