# Wrapping Text When Combining Columns in a Table

Tags: tables

I am trying to simply wrap the text centered across two columns. The text is long so wrapping is needed. However, the result truncates the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular} { |p{0.50\textwidth} |p{0.50\textwidth} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2} {|c|} 
{Number and Percent of Selected Cardiovascular Events by Treatment Group
 and Hazard Ratio From Cox Regression Analysis}\\
\hline
Data Information 1 & Data Information 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Your code isen't compilable,please edit. Does [Wrap text around wide figure in two column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124305/124842) help(image insteas table)?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be after a 2-column `tabular` where each column occupies 50% of the `\textwidth`. In these instances it's sometimes easier to use [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)'s `X`-column to spread things evenly. The calculation for the `\multicolumn` removes the column padding and rule width to ensure the `p`aragraph content fits within the remainder of `\textwidth` after those lengths are removed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | X | }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2} { | p{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth} | }{%
    Number and Percent of Selected Cardiovascular Events by Treatment Group
    and Hazard Ratio From Cox Regression Analysis} \\
  \hline
  Data Information 1 & Data Information 2 \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The column width calculations are a little more complicate:

- By default, the space `\tabcolsep` is added at the left and right side of a column.
- The rules have width `\arrayrulewidth`. The width contributes to the table width if package `array` is loaded.
- The column width for `\multicolumn` can also be calculated and column type `p` can be used.

Full example that shows the calculations if package `array` is loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular} {
  |p{.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}
  |p{.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2} {|>{\centering}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
{Number and Percent of Selected Cardiovascular Events by Treatment Group
 and Hazard Ratio From Cox Regression Analysis}\\
\hline
Data Information 1 & Data Information 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Further reading:

- [Package `tabularx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) for column type `X`, see Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389941/16967).
- [Package `booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for nicer tables with less lines.

Comment: Thank you. That works! I will need to study it a little to understand it.