# Wrapfigure in twocolumn text

Tags: two-column, wrapfigure

I am trying to wrap a figure in two column text, so that it cuts half of one column width and half of the other column. This is my example of MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquamtincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris. \begin{wrapfigure}[18]{r}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{8cm}
    \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=16\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Aliquamtincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi \begin{wrapfigure}[18]{l}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{8cm}
    \vfill
\end{wrapfigure} auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.Aliquamtincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

\end{document}
```

However, it only displays/cuts only one column but not the other column as shown on the image attached.

[image]

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that `wrapfig` can be used for such `twocolumn` wraps

Comment: I see. I saw some previous examples of people who managed to achieved what i am looking for, but i tried to replicate it, never managed to make it work, hence my question? is there another way of doing this then? Here is an example: [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124305/wrap-text-around-wide-figure-in-two-column)