# Three continuous columns, outer wrapped round inner

Tags: columns, wrap, flowfram

I'm trying to have text such that

- One set of paragraphs appear in the center of the page; when there is no more room, the text flows onto the next page (see blue area).
- Left of that, text wrapped around the central text such that it flows from 1, to 2, to 3; then, on a new page, back to 1 again , and so forth (see red area).
- Right side, text wrapped around the central text such that it flows from A, to B, to C; then, on a new page, back to A again , and so forth (see green area).

Ideally, the different texts would flow continually page by page (in their red, green or blue areas).

I suspect the solution is flowfram, and I've tried in vain to use [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512455/two-column-with-a-text-box-in-the-center-wrapping-on-both-sides) but I'm just not managing it...

[image: View of desired layout]

Comment: Yes, for complex documents layouts like this `flowfram` could be the easier solution. Check if  [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73572/11604) (with a different layout) help you to understand the syntax. The "but"  is that you cannot have fully automatic text flows  in blocks as 1, 2, 3  because the text width cannot be  changed in the middle of a paragraph, so is your task ensure that every block have only complete paragraphs or place a `\framebreak` when needed.

Comment: @Fran thanks so much: when I try, it seems like text goes from 3 to A. I understand why in most instances that would be useful but is there a way to have it so there are, essentially, three streams of text which are separate, though each appear on the page (if you see what I mean?)