# Position a figure at the center of a page despite other content

Tags: floats, positioning

This is my original document:

```
-------------------
|sec 1            |
|-----            |
||fig|            |
|-----            |
|                 |
|                 |
|      page1      |
-------------------
```

I'm hoping to position the figure to the center of the page, but after adding `[p]` to `\begin{figure}[p]`, I got 2 pages:

```
-------------------
|sec 1            |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|      page1      |
-------------------

-------------------
|                 |
|                 |
|      -----      |
|      |fig|      |
|      -----      |
|                 |
|      page2      |
-------------------
```

Is it possible to position the image in the center of the page even with other contents, like this?

```
-------------------
|sec 1            |
|                 |
|      -----      |
|      |fig|      |
|      -----      |
|                 |
|      page1      |
-------------------
```

Right now let's assume "other content" is simply the section title.

The only solution I have now is to measure the vertical space brought by the section title, and then compensate the same length at the bottom of the page and use two `\vfill` to center the figure vertically. But can it be done easier?

Code to get started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{sec 1}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics{noimage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not easily.  Flowfram is one possibility.  There is another package I've heard about (aebslicing?) but never used.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512455/two-column-with-a-text-box-in-the-center-wrapping-on-both-sides

Answer (score 1):

You can use tikz for that.
I assume you wanted the figure + its caption centred.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
    \section*{sec 1}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, overlay, remember picture]
    \node at (current page.center) {\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (fig) {\includegraphics{noimage}};
            \node [below=\belowcaptionskip of fig,text width=\linewidth] {\captionof{figure}{Caption}\label{fig}};
        \end{tikzpicture}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want only the picture at page centre, we can remove the second tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
    \section*{sec 1}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, overlay, remember picture]
            \node (fig) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics{noimage}};
            \node [below=\belowcaptionskip of fig,text width=\linewidth] {\captionof{figure}{Caption}\label{fig}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

For the subfigures, I use a matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \section*{sec 1}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, overlay, remember picture]
        \matrix[name=F, matrix of nodes, row sep=1ex, column sep={2em}, nodes={text width=.45\linewidth, anchor=center, align=center}] at (current page.center) {%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
            Subcaption a & Subcaption b\\
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\\
            Subcaption c & Subcaption d\\
        };
        \node [below =\belowcaptionskip of F, text width=\linewidth] {\captionof{figure}{Caption}\label{fig}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we insert subfigure into figure from `tikz`? I'm asking because my actual purpose is plotting multiple (4) subfigures into this figure and ideally this figure as a whole centered in a page.

Comment: One possibility is to use a matrix.