# Wrap text around a centered table in a two-column document

Tags: floats, text, wrap

I desire to wrap text around a table in a two-column document like the following:

```
      column 1                  column 2
---------------------    ---------------------
---------------------    ---------------------
---------------------    ---------------------
---------------                ---------------
--------------- CENTERED TABLE ---------------
---------------                ---------------
---------------------    ---------------------
---------------------    ---------------------
```

All solutions that I have already found are about using `wrapfig` or similar libraries to wrap text around the table in the right or the left side of the document.

Comment: Almost all solutions perhaps. But there are some that deal with this issue, like this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124305/47927

Comment: @JasperHabicht Unfortunately It is not working for tables.

Comment: You did not provide a minimal working example or some other code to work with, so all we can do is guessing what you want to achieve. As the answer to the linked question puts the stuff to be wrapped inside a `minipage`, it is possible to put in there whatever you want, including `tabluar` environments (which, essentially, are tables).