# Pullquotes not working

Tags: graphics, wrap, pullquote

I am want to wrap text around image using pull quote from [Two-column text with circular insert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert/70169#70169), but I wasn't able even to compile example file correctly. Is there anybody that has pull quotes working?

Image here: [Esperanto_star.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Esperanto_star.png) (direct link; licence: public domain, cf. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Esperanto_star.png)

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pullquote}

\begin{document}

\begin{pullquote}
{image={Esperanto_star},imageopts={scale=0.1},shape=rectangular}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{pullquote}

\begin{pullquote}
{image={Esperanto_star},imageopts={scale=0.1},shape=image}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{pullquote}

\end{document}
```

Example output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Can you post what you have?

Comment: You nee to have imagemagick installed for this to work. Do you have it?. It works for me on miktex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not tell us anything about your configuration, so let me write here first two points also written in documentation of [`pullquote`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pullquote.dtx):

- ImageMagick must be installed. In Windows it must be in system path *before* Windows folders (because in Windows a `convert.exe` with a fully other functionality exists). When you use the installer, this is done automatically, but for the portable version you have to make sure this on your own.
- You must compile with the option `-shell-escape` (for MiKTeX the original command is `-enable-write18`, but the former alias works, as well).

But there is a third point not explicitly mentioned:

When you give the option `shape=image`, then the image filename is handled over to ImageMagick’s `convert`, hence **you must give the file extension**! Otherwise `convert` will complain about this, but its error message is unfortunately not copied into the log file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pullquote}
\begin{document}

\begin{pullquote}
{image={Esperanto_star.png},imageopts={scale=0.1},shape=image}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{pullquote}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of example output]

The white space between the lower star beams is no error, but can by design not be avoided.

Comment: can you explain more how we can download ImageMagick? if you give us a like @Speravir

Comment: @MamounMohammed Just download from the program’s website: [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/).