# How to make "callouts" or "standout blurbs" among a larger body of text?

Tags: floats, boxes, book-design

I'm not sure what the word I need to search for is, to find help if this question has already been answered.

[image: Cosmo]

In magazines it's common to pick out words from the middle of a body of text and repeat them in larger font, with the rest of the text flowing around the "`\mbox{}`".

[image: callout blurb]

How do I make such floating "standout" text—not necessarily in red circles? What is the proper phrase to search for that identifies this way of emphasising short bits of text?

Comment: Like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert/70169#70169?

Comment: With LaTeX this is going to be very hard, as it is really tricky to combine TeX's mechanism for "run around text" (`\parshape`) with the positioning of the elements to be run around on the page. I've written a commercial package which can do this, so it's possible with TeX. For LaTeX probably the [flowfram package](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/manual/flowframesummary.html) is the nearest you can get.

Comment: Thanks @olga.saucedo, **pull quote** is the correct word I should be using here.