# How could I use ImageMagick to wrap text about figure?

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, quoting, shapepar, pullquote

I downloaded ImageMagick, then I convert the `convert.exe` file name to `imgconvert.exe`.
but the code still don't work. what should I do?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pullquote}
\begin{document}

\begin{pullquote}
{image={4.png},imageopts={scale=0.1},shape=image}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{pullquote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume you mean [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert/70169#70169) `pullquote` package. Do you satisfy the requirements from section 2.2 of the manual, most important: Is `convert` available from PATH? Why did you rename the `convert.exe` file? (As far as I remember, the `convert.exe` file from ImageMagick is considered legacy by the current installer and `magick.exe` is the new approach, as a `convert.exe` is already present in the `system32` directory of Windows systems.)