# Do I need to download Pullquotes.sty?

Tags: packages, texlive, csquotes, quoting, pullquote

If I have texlive, do I need to download  Pullquotes.sty?
If yes, from where? And what should I do after download?
I want to run this code: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70169/221341

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note it is `pullquote.sty` (lower case and no s)

It is not in texlive but there is a link to the source in the post that you reference.

Use the "download" link at

[http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pullquote.dtx](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Etex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/pullquote.dtx)

which will give you `pullquote.dtx` which is the documented source.

You can then run

```
tex pullquote.dtx
```

which will generate the package file `pullquote.sty`

To typeset the documentation you can use

```
pdflatex pullquote.dtx
```

You will need to download the sample images from the same place

[http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Etex-sx/tex-sx/development/files)

`pq-duck.pdf` and `pq-alice.jpg`

Running pdflatex on `pullquote.pdf` should then produce documentation, page 4 of which looks like

[image]

Note you need to use `--shell-escape` if you want the shape around the duck automatically calculated, I didn't do that here (or at least it didn't work when I tried it, I may not have all the auxiliary programs set up)