Defining a macro yielding acceptable output to \setlength command
My problem arose in the process of trying to solve a shapepar question/challenge (similar to this ---not fully solved--- one) in the following scenario:

Mimic rather simple page layout of children books, etc., where the placement of accompanying images conditions some part(s) of the text paragraphs.

Thus, on a per page basis, force if necessary, the beginning and the ending of pages, which allows for using the xfig + fig2dev + shapepar combo to generate the desired page layout to finally insert the image at the wanted position. [Further reference: 1) on using xfig and friends, 2) more on using xfig and friends, 3) on how shapepar works.]

After computing the absolute width (in dimensionless units, though, because this is what xfig + fig2dev yields) of the xfig drawing via a perl script (which I'll post here if someone requests so; using the RecDescent module, it parses the *.shape fig2dev generated file to perform the computation), the computed value is written into the *.shape file to be read and used by the main LaTeX file. This is needed because, as far as I am aware of, shapepar doesn't accept a dimension width to be the final width of the shaped paragraph. For the present purpose, the command doesn't behave in a "straightforward" way:

The only optional parameter accepted by shapepar is a scale value one, i.e., the user can optionally provide the dimension value (in legit units) that shapepar will take as equivalent to one dimensionless unit in the *.shape file in order to compute the final fixed paragraph width. [For the sake of completeness: shapepar's default behaviour aims to wrap as much text as possible in order to wrap it to the whole shape, at the cost of changing the paragraph width, which we do not want, of course.]

Therefore, the behaviour of shapepar's optional parameter becomes a handicap in the described scenario, where a fixed/absolute paragraph width is needed. So the idea is to perform the following computation: relative_scale_value_for_optional_shapepar_parameter_in_dimension_units = user_given_paragraph_width_in_dimension_units(*) / absolute_width_in_dimensionless_units_read_from_.shape_file to provide shapeparoptional parameter with the suitable argument info to get the intended final paragraph width.

This is (hopefully) done via a macro in the main LaTeX file: \fitToWidth{<(*)paragraph_width>}{<filename.shape>} with \textwidth being the default paragraph width value for the optional parameter. I said optional but wrote ordinary braces because \fitToWidth is actually meant to be used inside every ad hoc paragraph macro generated when modifying the *.shape file (cf. the code below) and I don't wanna mess with optional parameters inside optional parameters... [LaTeX complains about this and my skills can't cope with this problem].

Now here comes the problem: how to make the \fitToWidth macro acceptable as a dimension to be interpreted by the shapeparmacro, which is (or this is what I guess, but I'm probably wrong because of my ignorance about TeX/LaTeX) the same problem as making it acceptable to, say, \setlength.


NOTE:

When \fitToWidth is defined using xparse, the error says '\xparse function is not expandable'. I'm aware of this question, but I can't figure out what's really going on, as there's no solution posted and I'm obviously not a TeXnician.

The code with the wannabe \fitToWidth macro:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,microtype,blindtext}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\input{file.shape.modified}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\fitToWidth}[2]
% \cs_new_nopar:Npn \fit_to_width:nn #1#2
  {
    % Check if the file exists
    \file_if_exist:nTF {#2}
      {
        % Open .shape file for reading
        \ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior {#2}

        % Read until the desired line where the perl-computed value was written
        \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
        \bool_until_do:nn { \int_compare_p:nNn \l_tmpa_int = {10} }
          {
            \ior_str_get:NN \g_tmpa_ior \l_tmpa_str
            \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
          }

        % Close the file
        \ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior

        % Extract numeric value from line
        \regex_extract_once:nVN { \{\d+(?:\.\d+)\}\%(.+) } { \l_tmpa_str } \l_tmpa_seq

        % Compute the value to be interpreted as a dimension
        % I read 29.3 from interface3.pdf but it's pretty obvious I'm missing something/a lot
        \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
        { \dim_eval:n { \fp_to_dim:n { \textwidth / { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2} } } } }
        { \dim_eval:n { \fp_to_dim:n { #1 / { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2} } } } }

      }{
        % Abort compilation if the file doesn't exist
        \GenericError{FileNotFound}{The~file~'#2'~does~not~exist.}
      }
}

% % Final command to be used in the document
% % (actually, similar ad hoc commands are generated for every page/figure by the perl script.)
% %  This one is made available here in the main document via \input{file.shape.modified}
% \NewDocumentCommand{\filepar} {o m} {%
%   \IfNoValueTF {#1}
%   { % No scale-value given, use shapepar's default behaviour
%     \shapepar{\fileshape}#2\par
%   }{ % Provide shapepar with a properly computed scale value to make it build a paragraph according to the user-provided width
%     \shapepar[\fitToWidth{#1}{file.shape.modified}]{\fileshape}#2\par
%   }
% }
% \def\fileshape{%
% {25.0716}%50
% {0.0716332}b{3.51003}\\%
% {0.0716332}t{3.51003}{43.1232}\\%
% {0.143266}t{3.0086}{44.1261}\\%
% {0.286533}t{2.5788}{44.9857}\\%
% {0.501433}t{2.07736}{45.9885}\\%
% {0.787966}t{1.64756}{46.8481}\\%
% {1.0745}t{1.2894}{47.5645}\\%
% {1.43266}t{0.931232}{48.2808}\\%
% {1.86246}t{0.644699}{48.8539}\\%
% {2.29226}t{0.358166}{49.4269}\\%
% {2.7937}t{0.2149}{49.7135}\\%
% {3.29513}t{0.0716332}{50}\\%
% {30.1576}t{0.0716332}{29.0115}st{29.0831}{20.9885}\\%
% {33.9542}t{0.0716332}{28.216}e{50.0716}\\%
% {37.6791}t{0.0716332}{27.4355}\\%
% {48.4241}t{0.0716332}{32.4897}b{50.0716}\\%
% {57.0201}t{0.0716332}{36.533}jt{36.6046}{13.467}\\%
% {61.8911}t{0.0716332}{50}\\%
% {62.3925}t{0.0716332}{50}\\%
% {62.894}t{0.2149}{49.7135}\\%
% {63.3954}t{0.358166}{49.4269}\\%
% {63.8252}t{0.644699}{48.8539}\\%
% {64.255}t{0.931232}{48.2808}\\%
% {64.6132}t{1.2894}{47.5645}\\%
% {64.8997}t{1.64756}{46.8481}\\%
% {65.1862}t{2.07736}{45.9885}\\%
% {65.4011}t{2.5788}{44.9857}\\%
% {65.5444}t{3.0086}{44.1261}\\%
% {65.616}t{3.51003}{43.1232}\\%
% {65.616}e{46.6332}%
% }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% For reference:
\newlength{\WIDTH}\setlength{\WIDTH}{10pt}
Original WIDTH value: \the\WIDTH

For reference textwidth line For reference textwidth line For reference textwidth line
For reference textwidth line For reference textwidth line For reference textwidth line.

% Tests for a perl-script computed value of 50 dimensionless units' layout width:
% 1) default width: \textwidth
1) Parshape value for textwidth (\the\textwidth): \fitToWidth{}{file.shape.modified}\par%value is typeset, no errors reported
% 2) optional width specified:
2) Parshape value for 5cm: \fitToWidth{5cm}{file.shape.modified}\par%value is typeset, no errors reported
% 3) use as argument in \setlength: ERROR!
3) Setlength case using 4cm: \setlength{\WIDTH}{\fitToWidth{4cm}{file.shape.modified}}
\ WIDTH value:\ \the\WIDTH\ (Non-intended behaviour)\par
% a) .log errors:
% ! Missing number, treated as zero.
% <to be read again>
%                    \__kernel_tl_set:Nx
% l.104 ...H}{\fitToWidth{4cm}{file.shape.modified}}
%                                                   \ WIDTH value:\ \the\WIDTH...
%
% ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
% <to be read again>
%                    \__kernel_tl_set:Nx
% l.104 ...H}{\fitToWidth{4cm}{file.shape.modified}}
%                                                   \ WIDTH value:\ \the\WIDTH...
% b) typeset output corresponding to 3) line; instead of being taken as a dimension,
%    the computed value is typeset, an error is produced and WIDTH is set to 0.0pt (???):
% 3) 2.27621pt WIDTH value: 0.0pt

\bigskip

Intended use:

a) Default shapepar use, no \emph{scale value} given, automatically computed width:
\medskip

\filepar{\blindtext[3]}

\newpage

b) Custom use: not working, pararaph gets the same width as the default use and
the computed value is typeset, not interpreted.
\medskip

\filepar[4cm]{\blindtext[3]}
% a) .log errors:
% \filepar[4cm]{\blindtext[3]}
% ! Missing number, treated as zero.
% <to be read again>
%                    \__kernel_tl_set:Nx
% l.137 \filepar[4cm]{\blindtext[3]}
%
% ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
% <to be read again>
%                    \__kernel_tl_set:Nx
% l.137 \filepar[4cm]{\blindtext[3]}

\newpage

\bigskip

c) Raw shapepar use, \textbf{manually} adapted to fit a 370pt ($\Rightarrow$ 7.4pt) paragraph width.
Please note that there are no rounded corners at the bottom and the blank space isn't
fully outlined because there isn't enough text to get to these areas, which is the
desired behaviour in this scenario.
\medskip

\shapepar[7.4pt]{\fileshape}\blindtext[3]\par

\newpage

d) Example of text overflow yielding bad adjustments which, again, pose no problem in this scenario:

\shapepar[7.5pt]{\fileshape}\blindtext[4]\par

\end{document}



I've not looked at your code, but \NewExpandableDocumentCommand`` is the expandable equivalent of \NewDocumentCommand`.

Some suggestions: a) Show us an image of such a page, even a hand-sketch. b) Ad to your reading list the code for wrapstuff.  c) In many cases you will want to fit text around the contour of an image, not inside a shape. The latter impressive as they are have very little practical use. d) I would use Lua for all math and calculations, and start from scratch.  e) I would prefer not to use parshape, but build an algo from scratch. You will need some external program to slice an image into lines. Like in the early days of the web (still used in some instances).

... see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp. Take also some inspiration from ASCII ART algorithms. These are a bit different as they use different chars to emulate grayness. So my thoughts the algorithm will build the page line by line, only using boxes one word or per char if needed, leave empty hard space where an image-line needs to be inserted etc. In simpler cases parshape might also be used. Decompose the problem to smaller parts...

@cfr, yes I also tried this one and I got the same errors. And some latex3 variants with \exp_args and \cs_generate_variants: no luck. The code is ready to be tested. If you uncomment the lines corresponding to the "file.shape.modified" and put them into a file this same name located at the same dir as the .tex one, it runs and shows all the errors. Alternatively, you can uncomment these lines and \RenewDocumentCommand{\filepar} to fiddle with it without having to use an external file.

@yannisl thanks for your suggestions. Right now, after having spent many more hours of frustration than I'm willing to acknowledge, I'm more interested in the \setlength issue, which has no dependency relation with the page layout scenario. Hence the name of the question. I wrote about the layout problem to give context and to gather info about it just in case someone is interested in this problem.

@yannis, an example of this layout would be this one. Focusing on the right page, the elephant image affects the shape of the paragraph. The strategy I chose is being not clever (I'm no wizard programmer) but patient, i.e., to work page by page and creating an ad hoc layout for every page that needs it by isolating it and using xfig + shapepar + fixed parwidth to produce the desired layout, and then placing the image at will onto this isolated page.

shapepar seems rather unsuited to page layout as the whole point of the code is to  choose a size of the shape so the supplied text exactly fits into the square or circle etc, that is almost completely the opposite of what you want to do here where you have a fixed page size and want to arrange a non rectangular tex flow cutting out specific areas.

search this site for "pullquote" eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert/70169#70169

@DavidCarlisle, but I can use xfig to produce the desired layout: 1) fixed parwidth for the 'frame' of the paragraph, this is the crucial point, 2) within this frame, I choose at will (by roughly drawing them with xfig) which areas won't have text; they're meant to be blank to be 'filled' with images later. 3) The generated shapepar file contains this info (please look at c) item in the code), so I can confidently put the text knowing it will respect my blank/image spaces. The only thing I need then is to make shapepar accept the computation needed as explained in the question.

@DavidCarlisle, yes I also knew about that one, but it seems to be made for a twocolumn page layout. (I know my strategy is very cumbersome and it is indeed a workaround; but it can work reasonably well, provided the \fitToWidth macro yields something that shapepar can take as a legit argument.)

well it's your document and I am sure you can force shapepar to work but you are fighting to over-ride 90% of what the package is trying to do. For your actual question, look what pgfmath or xstring or other non-expandable calculation commands do: do not try to make it expandable to use inline in \setlength, define it to define a result macro say \result that expands to a length and can be used in \setlength and other contexts
